# How to open new website via selenium and than open new tab and close new tab and work with first tab in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

i tried to work with selenium web driver for this plan " i open new link via selenium web driver on example website called `scene-rls` and do some work in this site and after i open new tab to open `google.com` then do some works and close the `google` tab and back to `scene-rls` tab and do new work on the `scene-rls` tab , but in my code when i open `google.com`  and close the tab and  back to the `scene-rls` tab the code return error like this:

`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchWindowException: Message: no such window: window was already closed`

and my code is :

```
  Regular_part = "Ambulance Australia S02E05 WEB H264-FLX"
  driver = 
webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C://chromdriver//chromedriver.exe')

x = True
while x:
    driver.get('http://scene-rls.net/?s='+Regular_part+'&submit=Find')

    time.sleep(5)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[1]/div[2]/h1/a').click()

    print("Opent new tab")
    driver.execute_script("window.open ('https://google.com', 'new window')")

    time.sleep(3)
    print("back scn tab")

    driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[0])

    time.sleep(3)
    print("back google tab")

    driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])
    driver.execute_script("window.close ('https://google.com', 'new window')")


    z = input(":::")
    if z == "y":
        x = True
    else:
        x = False
```

Comment: There's no need to use JSE to close a tab. While the context is in that tab, use `drvier.close()` to close the tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After closing to window you have to Switch back to previous window again.

```
driver.execute_script("window.close ('https://google.com', 'new window')")
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
```

Comment: dud can you help me about this error? `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` i want to use variable in place of link the code is  `xx = "http://scene-rls.net/?s='"+Regular_part+"'&submit=Find"
 driver.execute_script("window.open ("+xx+", 'new window')")`

Comment: Try that. `xx = "http://scene-rls.net/?s='"+Regular_part+"'&submit=Find"
driver.execute_script('''window.open("{},_blank");'''.format(xx))`